# Bootstrap: Generate Label on right bottom corner of <li> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a productlist of a bootstrap template with `<li>` tags:

```
<div class="category-products">
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
        <li class="item first">
            <div class="product-image"> <a href="#"> <img class="small-image" src="IMAGE.jpg" width="230"> </a> </div>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
                    <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="desc std">
                    <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Now I want a label "New Product" in the right bottom corner. How can I make it?

Bootstrap has standard labels like this:

```
<span class="label label-info">Info</span>
```

But the are not in the corner :)

Comment: Why don´t you use css to move it? with position absolute and then you can play with left and top values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```css
.products-list>.item {
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.products-list>.item .product-image {
  margin: -15px -15px 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.products-list>.item .product-image>a {
  width: 100%;
}
.products-list>.item span.label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px 0;
}
ol,
ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="category-products">
  <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <li class="item first">
      <div class="product-image">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="small-image" src="http://placehold.it/260x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-shop">
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
        <div class="price-box">
          <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
          <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desc std">
          <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
          <span class="label label-info">New Product</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li class="item first">
      <div class="product-image">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="small-image" src="http://placehold.it/260x150" width="260">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-shop">
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
        <div class="price-box">
          <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
          <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desc std">
          <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
          <span class="label label-info">New Product</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li class="item first">
      <div class="product-image">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="small-image" src="http://placehold.it/260x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-shop">
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
        <div class="price-box">
          <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
          <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desc std">
          <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
          <span class="label label-info">New Product</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li class="item first">
      <div class="product-image">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="small-image" src="http://placehold.it/260x150">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-shop">
        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
        <div class="price-box">
          <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
          <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span>  <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="desc std">
          <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
          <span class="label label-info">New Product</span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Relevant part:

```
.products-list>.item {
  position: relative;
}
.products-list>.item span.label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

The code assumes your labels are already inside your descriptions. If they aren't they can be generated on the fly, but it's not clear from your question you want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap styles for this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/1bLhvj9o/)

```
<div class="category-products">
  <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <li class="item first">
        <div class="product-image"> <a href="#"> <img class="small-image" src="IMAGE.jpg" width="230"> </a> </div>
        <div class="product-shop">
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
            <div class="price-box">
                <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
                <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="desc std">
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><span class="label label-info pull-right">New Product</span></a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you. But you can see in my last comment top of your answer that tha label is not in the bottom of LI. The desc std is not so height

Comment: @Koda, you can move it in any place

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the style float right

See here: 
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/t3o221zx/)

```
<div class="category-products">
<ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <li class="item first">
        <div class="product-image"> <a href="#"> <img class="small-image" src="IMAGE.jpg" width="230"> </a> </div>
        <div class="product-shop">
            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">PRODUCTNAME</a></h2>
            <div class="price-box">
                <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span id="old-price-212" class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
                <p class="special-price"> <span class="price-label"></span> <span class="price"> XXXXX </span> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="desc std">
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
            <span class="label label-info" style="float: right" >Info</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you. But so the label is under the description and not on the bottom of the LI TAG. The CSS Code is too mutch to post. I have search a Template with a similar Code. [link](http://demo.magikthemes.com/index.php/lambygreen/girls.html?mode=list) cou see when you past your Code with Firebug the label is not on the bottom of LI